# Laravel duplicate entry after force delete

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Working on a Laravel 4.2 app (yes, it's an older app not worth upgrading)

Trying handle the case where a user was soft deleted and wants to create an account again.

Having the issue that registering a new user doesn't work as the 'email' column is unique and the soft deleted record still exists.

I would much rather prefer to create a new user record (with all other fields empty), with same incrementing ID to keep relations with other soft deleted records.

So physically delete the old record and create a new one with the old ID? Right? Not working.

Calling forceDelete() on the record works, it does remove it from the Database, but then trying to create a new record immediately afterward throws a 'duplicate key' exception. Refreshing the page it is no longer a problem, as it doesn't see the old record.

It seems that the error is coming from MYSQL itself, though php should be waiting for a response to the delete query before executing the insert query, so mysql should know at this point that the record has been removed.

Is it possible that this error is actually coming from some sort of memory cache in Laravel?

I am also using the Sentinel authentication package, if that is of relevance.

Here is the basic code:

```
$found = User::where('email', $email)->first();

if ($found->deleted_at) {

    $old_id = $found->id;

    $found->forceDelete();
    $found->save();

    $unique_id = $this->generateUnique(NULL, $first_name . $last_name);

    $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate(array(
        'id' => $old_id,
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'unique_id' => $unique_id,
        'preferred_lang' => $this->locale,
    ));
}
```

This results in a

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'whoever@mail.com' for key 'users_email_unique'

Does anyone know why this is? Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got my code to work...

I read somewhere that I had to call

`$found->save()`

to update the deleted record, but that still had not worked for me.

Oddly enough, switching to

`$found->update()`

worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent):

To restore a soft deleted model into an active state, use the restore method:

```
$user->restore();
```

To determine if a given model instance has been soft deleted, you may use the trashed method:

```
if ($user->trashed())
{
//
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear that I did not want to simply restore the record. The reason for this is I want it to appear as a new user record, and I create history based on the model events. I.E. restoring would result in an 'updated' history instead of a 'created'.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore deleted row like this:

```
$deletedRow = User::withTrashed()->where('email', $email)->first();
if($deletedRow) {
      $deletedRow->restore();
}
```